# STM32L073RZ (rev Z) IAP jump to bootloader (system memory)

Tags: stm32, bootloader

I use the STM32L073RZ (Nucleo 64 board).

I would like to jump into the system memory in application programming (IAP).

My code works on the revision B of the STM32L073 microcontroller but fails on the latest revision, rev Z.

I read the errata sheet, no details are given, just a limitation fixed on the dual boot mechanism into system memory according to the BFB2 bit.

Is the system memory no longer supports an IAP jumping to execute its code (to flash firmwares through USB or UART without using the BOOT0 pin) ?

The function is the first line of my main program, it tests if the code has to jump to the booloader:

```
void jumpBootLoader(void)
{
    /* to do jump? */
    if ( *((unsigned long *)0x20003FF0) == 0xDEADBEEF  ) 
    {
        /* erase the label */
        *((unsigned long *)0x20003FF0) = 0xCAFEFEED;

        /* set stack pointer to the bootloader start address */
        __set_MSP(*((uint32_t*)(0x1FF00000)));

        /* system memory mapped at 0x00000000 */
        __HAL_SYSCFG_REMAPMEMORY_SYSTEMFLASH();

        /* jump to @bootloader + 4 */
        ((void (*)(void))(*((uint32_t*)(0x1FF00004))))();
    }
}
```

I call these two lines as soon as the BP1 button is pressed to trig the jump operation after resetting the µC:

```
*((unsigned long *)0x20003FF0) = 0xDEADBEEF;
NVIC_SystemReset();
```

I use the HSI 16Mhz clock source.

Comment: Most likely no one will be able to help you if you don't show us the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to jump twice to the system memory.
First Jump to bootloader startup to initialize Data in RAM until the Program counter will returned to Flash by the Dualbank management.
Second Jump: Jump to the  Dualbank bypassed address

How to use: User has first to initialize a variable “ Data_Address”  (must be an offset Flash sector aligned address) in Flash to distinguish between first/second Jump.

```
EraseInitStruct.TypeErase   = FLASH_TYPEERASE_PAGES;
EraseInitStruct.PageAddress = Data_Address;
EraseInitStruct.NbPages     = 1;


    First_jump = *(__IO uint32_t *)(Data_Address);

    if (First_jump == 0) {  
        HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
        HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_WORD, Data_Address, 0xAAAAAAAA);
        HAL_FLASH_Lock();

        /* Reinitialize the Stack pointer and jump to application address */ 
        JumpAddress = *(__IO uint32_t *)(0x1FF00004);
    }
    if (First_jump != 0) {  
        HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
        HAL_FLASHEx_Erase(&EraseInitStruct, &PAGEError);
        HAL_FLASH_Lock();

        /* Reinitialize the Stack pointer and jump to application address */ 
        JumpAddress =  (0x1FF00369);
    }

    Jump_To_Application = (pFunction) JumpAddress;
    __set_MSP(*(__IO uint32_t *)(0x1FF00000));
    Jump_To_Application();
```

Answer (score 1):

First important thing: you use `0x1FF0 0000` as the addres where SP is stored, this is correct. Then you use `0x1 FF00 0004` as the address from which you load the function pointer. This is not correct - one zero too many.

Note that using `__set_MSP()` is generally not such a good idea if you also use MSP as your stack pointer (which you most likely are). The recent definition of this function, which marks "sp" as clobbered register, causes your change to be reverted almost immediately. Incidentally today I was doing exactly the same thing you are doing and I've found that problem. In your assembly listing you'll see that SP is saved into some other register before the `msr msp, ...` instruction and restored right after that.

Finally I wrote that manually (STM32F4, so different addresses):

```
constexpr uint32_t systemMemoryBase {0x1fff0000};

asm volatile
(
        "   msr     msp, %[sp]      \n"
        "   bx      %[pc]           \n"

        ::  [sp] "r" (*reinterpret_cast<const uint32_t*>(systemMemoryBase)),
            [pc] "r" (*reinterpret_cast<const uint32_t*>(systemMemoryBase + 4))
);
```

BTW - you don't need to set memory remap for the bootloader to work.

Comment: Sorry for '0x1FF0 0 0004', I failed the copy/past of my code, I corrected it in my post. Is it a c++ code ? 'constexpr' and 'reinterpret_cast'  do not compile for me, I used 'const' and a simple cast expression '(uint32_t*)' instead. I tested my code without calling __set_MSP(), it still works...

Comment: @hbevil - yes, the code snippet I posted is C++11, but your changes are ok too. As for the rest of your comment - "it still works..." or maybe it still fails to work? (;

Comment: yes, it 'still works' on stm32l073 revision B, and 'still fails to work' on rev Z although it is the same code... I see that the Bootloader versions are different, v4.0 for rev B and 4.1 for rev Z.

Comment: @hbevil - even if the jump to bootloader is the first thing you do in main(), it doesn't mean that it's the first thing the firmware is doing. Most likely - if you use HAL/SPL - the clocks in RCC are initialized before main(), and one of the requirements to execute the bootloader is to run it with "reset state" of everything, including RCC clocks and PLL settings. Please also post the updated code in your question and verify the assembly output to see whether it's correct (you can post it here too).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help. I have my answer !

The v4.0 bootloader (initial version) does not implement the dual bank mechanism but this feature is supported by v4.1.

Software can jump to bootloader but it will execute the dual boot mechanism.
So the bootloader goes back to bank1 (or bank2 if a code is "valid").

Today it is not possible to bypass the dual bank mechanism to execute the bootloader with my configuration: 
The boot0 pin is reset and the protection level is 0 (see "Table 11. Boot pin and BFB2 bit configuration" in the reference manual).

Answer (score 0):

Where is your program counter when you call `__HAL_SYSCFG_REMAPMEMORY_SYSTEMFLASH()`?

Remapping a memory region while you're executing out of that same region will end poorly! You may need to relocate this code into SRAM, or execute this code with PC set to the fixed FLASH memory mapping (`0x0800xxxx`).